# What are the user defined key's value restrictions?

Tags: arangodb

In ArangoDB, when a collection is defined to allow user defined keys, what are the restrictions on the value of the key?  For example, it appears that a key of `"Name-2"` works but a key of `"Name,2"` gives `ArangoError 1221: invalid document key` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting from [the manual](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/DataModeling/NamingConventions/DocumentKeys.html)

- The key must be a string value. Numeric keys are not allowed, but any numeric value can be put into a string and can then be used as document key.
- The key must be at least 1 byte and at most 254 bytes long. Empty keys are disallowed when specified (though it may be valid to completely omit the `_key` attribute from a document)
- It must consist of the letters `a-z` (lower or upper case), the digits `0-9` or any of the following punctuation characters: `_` `-` `:` `.` `@` `(` `)` `+` `,` `=` `;` `$` `!` `*` `'` `%`
- Any other characters, especially multi-byte UTF-8 sequences, whitespace or punctuation characters cannot be used inside key values
- The key must be unique within the collection it is used

Keys are case-sensitive, i.e. `myKey` and `MyKEY` are considered to be different keys.

Comment: Thanks for the link, we just couldn't seem to find the right spot in the manual!

Comment: @stj The restrictions changed in the meanwhile, maybe you could edit your post. Commas are now valid according to the documentation. New documentation link (yours point to the index): https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/DataModeling/NamingConventions/DocumentKeys.html

Answer (score 1):

Restrictions (or naming conventions) for user defined keys can be found in docs [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/NamingConventions/DocumentKeys.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, we just couldn't seem to find it in the manual!